# Nlog TraceTarget outputs exe-file when LogLevel Info

Tags: c#, wpf, nlog

I have WPF app and i config Nlog from code:

NlogConfig.cs

```
public class NlogConfig
{
private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
public static void Configure(string path, LogLevel minLevel, LogLevel maxLevel)
{
    var layout = @"${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss} ${level:padding=-5:fixedlength=true} | ${callsite:padding=30:fixedlength=true:inner=Layout:alignmentOnTruncation=right} | ${message}";
    var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile") { FileName = path };
    logfile.ArchiveAboveSize = 20_971_520;
    logfile.MaxArchiveFiles = 1;
    logfile.Layout = layout;
    var traceconsole = new NLog.Targets.TraceTarget("traceconsole");
    traceconsole.Layout = layout;


    // Rules for mapping loggers to targets            
    var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();
    config.AddRule(minLevel, maxLevel, traceconsole);
    config.AddRule(minLevel, maxLevel, logfile);

    // Apply config           
    LogManager.Configuration = config;
    Logger.Debug("Nlog configured");
}
```

When I log message using Debug I get output like this:

`2023-10-23 16:06:22 Debug | iguration.NlogConfig.Configure | Nlog configured`

But when I use Info I get such output:

`test.exe Information: 0 : 2023-10-23 16:08:44 Info  | iguration.NlogConfig.Configure | Nlog configured`

What I did wrong why the output for Debug and Info different? I want to use the same layout for all log levels.

UPD:

In log.txt everything fine. But when I switch NLog.Targets.TraceTarget to NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget the log messages in console is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enable [RawWrite](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/P_NLog_Targets_TraceTarget_RawWrite.htm) = `true` for `TraceTarget`:

```cs
    var traceconsole = new NLog.Targets.TraceTarget("traceconsole");
    traceconsole.RawWrite = true;
    traceconsole.Layout = layout;
```

> **Layout Options**
>
> **rawWrite** - Always use `Trace.WriteLine` independent of LogLevel. `Default: False`
>
> Introduced with NLog 4.5, fixes the issue with output being prefixed with exe-filename.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Trace-target